# What is the maximum voltage gain that this amplifier can provide?

Tags: amplifier

Consider the following amplifier circuit operated with a supply voltage 
\$ V_{CC}=+3V \$. Assume \$ V_{do} = 0.7V, _A=∞, =100, V_{sat} = 0.3V, V_T = 25mV, V_{do} = 0.7V\$.

I am stuck on this problem. I have tried drawing a small signal model for the circuit, but I do not have values for any of the resistors. I cannot find the small signal parameters \$ g_m, r_{pi}, r_o \$ because I do not know the value of the DC current flowing through the branch.

Note: This problem did not come with a schematic.

Comment: You don't need any resistor values to work out the maximum voltage gain. You need to know \$V_\text{CC}\$ (which you know) and \$V_T\$ (which you know) and the minimum quiescent collector voltage you are willing to accept (with all the distortion that may go along with some of the crazier choices available to you.) By the way, you listed \$V_{do}\$ twice. (Obviously, this will have to be an AC grounded-emitter design for maximum voltage gain.)

Comment: Vsat=0.3V does not affect gain but it does affect output linear swing.. You cannot spec max gain , unless you spec max signal and max distortion.

Comment: Once you find your collector current, you're pretty much ready to solve your small signal parameters.

Comment: @KingDuken I figured, but how do I find the collector current?

Comment: @jonk Am I supposed to guess a value for the collector current?

Comment: @Hector No. Actually, that doesn't matter. You are supposed to work out why it doesn't matter and see for yourself.

Comment: *Consider the following amplifier circuit* What circuit? Sure it's probably just a common emitter circuit or is it? Use google to find a picture and include that.

Comment: I don't see a circuit in the question?

Comment: I can has schematic? Y u no add?

Comment: The problem did not come with a circuit schematic!!!!

Comment: And the name of a book is ?

Answer (score 3):

I can't provide you a direct answer -- only you know what's being asked of you -- but it's kind of painful to leave you in a lurch, too, squirming over the question of the quiescent current. So I'll draw out some simple logic and leave it to you to work things out for yourself, from there.

The highest voltage gain that can be hoped for with a BJT uses a grounded emitter. Without wasting time right now on DC biasing questions, the circuit will look something like this very simple behavioral example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRM3o6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We expect the *magic biasing network* to set things up such that, without a signal input being applied, the DC biasing point will place \$V_\text{C}\$ at a nominal, quiescent point we'll call \$V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}\$.

The quiescent collector current is then:

$$I_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}=\frac{V_\text{CC}-V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}{R_\text{C}}$$

We know also then that the quiescent dynamic emitter resistance is approximately:

$$r_e^{\,'}\approx \frac{V_T}{I_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}$$

(Technically, it's smaller by the factor \$\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\$, but who is counting? And since I also didn't take into account the Ohmic \$r_b\$ or \$r_e\$, which probably have a larger impact anyway, you'll just have to accept this simplification for now.)

The instantaneous voltage gain at that quiescent collector voltage is then:

$$A_v = \frac{R_\text{C}}{r_e^{\,'}}\approx \frac{R_\text{C}}{\left[\frac{V_T}{I_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}\right]}=\frac{R_\text{C}\:I_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}{V_T}=\frac{R_\text{C}}{V_T}\cdot\frac{V_\text{CC}-V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}{R_\text{C}}=\frac{V_\text{CC}-V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}{V_T}$$

So, you can see that the maximum voltage gain doesn't depend on the quiescent collector current. The maximum instantaneous voltage gain depends on where you set the quiescent collector voltage. And if you set it very low, such that the BJT is already well into saturation, then only slightly more than half of the input signal will experience that high gain. The other half will be mostly clipped away, as it drives the BJT only still deeper into saturation. Even if you avoid this problem, pushing towards maximum voltage gain means serious distortion if the input signal is anything but insubstantially small.

So what's the answer to your question? Up to you.

---

The above takes a simplified view. I'm assuming the device temperature is stable and I didn't deal with the Early Effect or \$r_o\$. Nor did I take into account the three Ohmic resistances associated with any realistic device or any of the charge storage issues, which may or may not be important in some circumstance. And I'm not interested in attempting any of that here. I just wanted to get a basic point across.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is no voltage gain , only current gain.

A small voltage on the base (in case of a BJT) creates a big current due to diffusion of many majority charge carriers from emmiter to base and then those become minority charge carriers inside the pn junction of base-collector.

Increased voltage on the collector will decrease the number of diffused charge carriers to base but will increase their drift velocity inside the base-collector junction so it is unclear.

Note that i dont know math or any equations related to the issue but i can help you qualitively.

Comment: A transistor has only current gain, that's true.  A circuit with a transistor can have voltage gain, and determining the gain for a given circuit is the task Hector was given.

Comment: How can it have voltage gain since it would violate the law of conversation of energy?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  An amplifier draws power from the supply (batteries or what ever.)  It is entirely possible to have voltage gain and current gain in one amplifier circuit .  That's kind of the whole point of amplifiers.  You feed in a low power signal and get a more powerful signal out.  Since you have a source of additional power, conservation of energy isn't a problem.  You just have to provide the required energy from an external source.

Comment: If you think amplifiers with voltage gain violate the conservation if energy, then you need to back up and get a better grasp of what energy **is.**

Comment: I dont argue there is current gain ,but voltage gain seems impossible to me.

Comment: [Work your way through this site from Analog.](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-9)  Once you've done that, you'll know where voltage gain comes from.

Comment: Will do.JRE do you know what energy is then?

Comment: In electronics, energy is the product of power and time.  Power is the product of voltage and current.  Energy is the product of voltage and current and time.

Comment: JRE thats the mathematical description of energy.I was asking for the qualitive one.

Comment: [Have a look here.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/electricalenergy)

Comment: The article doesnt explain what it is , it is just says it is the product of power and timeok it shows a cube but still what is it?Is it a car , what is it anyway?Wheb it says the resistor consumes energy 1 joule in 1 second it still doesnt explain what it is?What object is energy or what state?

Comment: It is what the definition says it is.  It is abstract.  Use the math.

Comment: @MrsChemistry A better qualititative discussion regarding energy on the web is found [here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html). It's a quantity we've found is conserved in nature. (It has dimensional units, as well. Dimensional analysis is also a very important skill to develop.) But the OP's question remains at a level that emerges above the one you are attempting. Just as entropy and temperature emerge as statistical large-population phenomena surrounding energy, where energy itself remains meaningful at a non-statistical, individual particle level.